# Quantifier free formula equivalents

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let $P_{i,j}$ be quantifier free first order formulas (finitely many), let $\forall P$ denote the universal closure of the formula $P$. The question is: is there a quantifier free formula $Q$ such that $\bigvee_j\bigwedge_i\forall P_{i,j}$ is logially equivalent to $\forall Q$?

Comment: Yes. If you look into the rules for converting a formula into [prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form), you will find that when you move a universal quantifier up through conjunctions and disjunctions it remains a universal quantifier.

Comment: This is not true I am afraid. Nevertheless, I solved it simply using the fact $\forall P_{i,j}$ is closed and then just renaming the bounded variables will move the quantifiers outside.

Comment: What is not true? The quantifiers remain universal when you move them up  from positive positions in the formula (i.e., all positions in a formula containing only disjunctions and conjunctions)  and of course you need to rename bound variables as necessary to avoid capture. All of this is explained in the Wikipedia link I gave. Your "simple" solution is just the relevant special case of prenex normalisation.

Comment: You are correct, in this case, moving $\forall$ is OK, but it is not in general.